# NanoPi NEO - Sharing files inside linux file system over micro USB port

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, usb, usb-otg, nanopi

I would like to transfer files from NanoPi NEO to PC over USB A (PC) - Micro USB (NanoPi) connection. I have files inside linux file system which i would like to be reachable to PC when connected over USB.

When i connect NanoPi NEO to the PC, the NanoPi NEO acts as a slave device but it is not showing the linux file structure. I think it is showing me the linux image files.

[File explorer, when NanoPi is connected over USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDHBb.png)